# Idris - equality assertion fails

Tags: idris

Please consider the following function, even if the implementation is not that relevant:

```
vectTranspose : Vect n (Fin 3) -> Vect 3 (List (Fin n))
vectTranspose {n = Z} [] = [[],[],[]]
vectTranspose {n = (S len)} (x :: xs) with (natToFin len (S len))
    | Just l = let
        previous = map (map weaken) (vectTranspose xs)
    in updateAt x (l ::) previous
```

if I try to compute `vectTranspose` in the REPL, I get `[[],[],[]]` as expected.

Still, if I add an equality assertion like the following in my code

```
emptyTest : vectTranspose [] = [[],[],[]]
emptyTest = Refl
```

then I get a compile error:

```
When checking right hand side of emptyTest with expected type
        vectTranspose [] = [[], [], []]

Type mismatch between
        [[], [], []] = [[], [], []] (Type of Refl)
and
        vectTranspose [] = [[], [], []] (Expected type)

Specifically:
        Type mismatch between
                [[], [], []]
        and
                vectTranspose []
```

Am I missing something? Should I specify somehow the type of `[[],[],[]]` in the assertion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that idris complains about the type of

```
Specifically:
    Type mismatch between
            [[], [], []]
    and
            vectTranspose []
```

indicates that `vectTranspose` is still in the type and has not been resolved. That is the case if vectTranspose is not total and indeed it is not:

```
VecTest.vectTranspose is possibly not total due to:
with block in VecTest.vectTranspose, which is not total as there are missing cases
```

which happens because you have not covered all the `Maybe` cases.

A simple solution could be to create a small helper function:

```
total
natToFin': (n: Nat) -> Fin (S n)
natToFin' Z = FZ
natToFin' (S k) = FS (natToFin' k)

total
vectTranspose : Vect n (Fin 3) -> Vect 3 (List (Fin n))
vectTranspose {n = Z} [] = [[], [], []]
vectTranspose {n = (S len)} (x :: xs) with (natToFin' len)
    vectTranspose {n = (S len)} (x :: xs) | l = let
           previous = map (map weaken) (vectTranspose xs)
           in updateAt x (l ::) previous
```

Comment: thanks! If I add the `Nothing` case it works. Still, the `Nothing` case is not reachable, since `natToFin len (S len)` is always `Just l`. If I use `| Nothing impossible`, the problem remains, even if I tag the function as total. Is there a way to make it works without providing a real `Nothing` case which will never be reached?

Comment: I am fairly sure there is a more elegant approach, but a simple one is to provide a small helper which covers your case. I am also not sure what your function is doing, so it could be that you end up with something entirely different at the end of the day.